# FMA Feature parameter records do not show up for every license record in LMA

Tags: managed-package, lma

We just released a new version of our appexchange app to set of customers.
This new version includes FMA (Feature Management App).
The issue is some org's licenses (in LMA) do not show Feature Parameter records listed under their License detail page.

Answer (score 0):

Got response back from salesforce that there was a known issue which was fixed recently :[Known issue](https://success.salesforce.com/issues_view?id=a1p3A000000mDWoQAM&title=feature-parameter-records-are-not-created-if-the-package-is-upgraded-on-sandbox-refreshed-from-a-org-the-package-is-already-installed) which means either of Sandbox or prodcution could be impacted of this issue. To fix it goto License record of impacted org and simply make a change e.g. Expiration Date and hit save it should trigger the SF back end process to Sync FMA records between subscriber org and LMO org.

Comment: We are considering adding FMA to our app. How has been your experience with it? Has it made your life easier? Any surprises?

Comment: Sure.. it is a great extension to LMA.. we had some issues in the very beginning but most of the critical ones salesforce fixed and now it seems pretty stable. Although there would be some surprises like sometimes the sync operation takes time since it happens in asynchronous fashion. Other thing to consider is if there is an exception thrown by FMA SF class you can't catch it so be aware of that means if SF mess up something in their release you will see the impact but that happened only once since the implementation (we are using it for almost 2 years now).

Comment: Not to mention you cannot test it in unmanaged environment and it is not testable in sandbox of your LMO same as LMA